# Ошибка Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Local to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6, npgsql

Заапдейтил проекты на .NET 6 и nuget-пакеты до последней стабильной. EFCore сейчас во всех проектах 6.0 (на самом деле чуть выше, но это не имеет значения). Погуглив я нашел следующий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69961449/17025310) на SO, а так же некоторую [информацию](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html?tabs=annotations#opting-out-of-the-new-timestamp-mapping-logic) от Npgsql, все ответы добавляют какие-то новые классы для конверта, атрибуты и еще много непонятно чего, поэтому воспроизводить их не особо хочется. Как можно решить данную проблему?

> Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Local to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.
> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Local to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.

Comment: Любопытно. Походил по ссылкам, почитал. В целом, я одобряю изменения. / Как решить? Можно попробовать переключить switch в старое поведение. / Но лучше в коде всегда использовать Utc - это избавит от всех возможных проблем.

Comment: Изменил теги: думаю, метка EF в данном вопросе существеннее. чем asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все же немного посидев я принял решение не сопротивляться и написать следующую строчку:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
```

перед `Build().Run()`. Так же, её можно вынести в метод `ConfigureServices`, если таковой у вас имеется. Это решило мою проблему. Возможно в WPF надо будет написать где-то в конструкторе или методе `OnStartup`